# What's the worst case for strongly regular graph's isomorphism algorithm?

Tags: graph-theory, isomorphism-testing, strongly-regular-graph

A new algorithm of *Graph Isomorphism* is invented by PCT/CN2020/134861, roughly speaking time complexity  $\leqslant5n^2$ except for regular graph, automorphism group can be known as by-product. Peer reviewed paper can be downloaded from [www.getpaperfree.com](http://www.getpaperfree.com) by search "同构", it is written in Chinese.

Except strongly regular graph, all other regular graph's isomorphism can be decided in $O(n^3)$.

After 2 years' hard work, though I am almost sure that time complexity  $\ll O(n^{\ln n})$ when $n$ is big enough for all graphs, time complexity $\leqslant O(n^5)$ for almost all strongly regular graphs, fail to know what's the worst case.

If you know a good classification of strongly regular graphs or other useful algorithm for them, please answer the question.
Thank you!

***Update***. *CaiFurerImmermanGraph  defeat my algorithm after test, but my original paper claims that almost all graphs has less than $5n^2$ time complexity,  weaker than the claim in question.*

Comment: Also posted to https://solveforum.com/forums/threads/whats-the-worst-case-for-strong-regular-graphs-isomorphism-algorithm.1251522/ (but what does PCT/CN2020/134861 mean?).

Comment: @GerryMyerson  Thank you for post it  at other place.  The Patent Cooperation Treaty (PCT) .  By search  PCT/CN2020/134861 on https://patentscope.wipo.int/search/en/search.jsf, you can find  translated versions of abstract from original apply in Chinese.  But the offical translation is very bad done by machine.

Comment: How does the algorithm in question perform on the graphs from

Cai, JY., Fürer, M. & Immerman, N. An optimal lower bound on the number of variables for graph identification. Combinatorica 12, 389–410 (1992). https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01305232

They provide counterexamples to all the claimed in the past polynomial time complexity graph isomorphism algorithms.

Comment: @DimaPasechnik your question is very good,  the high efficiency is based on establishing equations ( select subgraphs) randomly and solve them easily, in other words,  crossover classification of the two graphs' subgraph.  Among 10^12 cases , no  can defeat probability theory until now. If G and H are not isomorphic, for most cases,  establishing equations not more than twice, we can see no solution for such equations, thus they are not isomorphic.   Based on that,  subgraph isomorphism algorithm is developed , it is  more than 10000 times faster than one famous algorithm for difficult cases.

Comment: @DimaPasechnik  If you  provide test set for such counterexamples, I am glad to test it .

Comment: The potential counterexamples are described in the paper I cited. From what you wrote, it appears to me that your algorithm is actually just a randomised heuristic. No amount of experiments can show you have an algorithm.

Comment: you can generate these examples (Cai-Immerman graphs) in Sagemath:
https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/graphs/sage/graphs/generators/families.html#sage.graphs.generators.families.CaiFurerImmermanGraph

Comment: @DimaPasechnik  Thank you very much! I like Sagemath, but it give me a surprise today, it can not relabel graphs as I edited in question.  And as I observed  one example that even if the graphs has  4960 nodes with 144115188075855872 automorphism_group().order(), according to my experiance, It can not become couterexample to my polynomial algorithm (except the graphs are strongly regular ).  Please help me to relabel graph, I'am eager to know the test result.

Comment: Cai-Immerman graphs are not strongly regular, in general.

Comment: @DimaPasechnik   I agree with you, though Cai-Immerman graphs are not strongly regular in general, it is tough for almost all algorithm.  I  try to modify my program to be able to  handle  graphs with complex label though algorithm's efficiency will come down . Within one week,  answer will be there.   Anyway I believe there is no polynomial algorithm for graph isomorphism.

Comment: @DimaPasechnik   Bad news, after test, I found  Cai-Immerman graphs defeat my algorithm.  Thus I should edit my question to agree with my paper  which claim that almost all graphs ' time complexity < $5n^2$

Comment: "almost all" graphs - it's known, I think, that almost all graphs have simple spectrum of the adjacency matrix, and for such a case there is an old polynomial time algorithm by Babai, Grigoriev, and  Mount https://doi.org/10.1145/800070.802206

Answer (score -1):

Surprised to know there are two $O(n^3)$ isomorphic algorithms for **simple and undirected graphs** based on distance matrix.

DOI 10.16383/j.aas.c230025.
Wang Zhuo, Wang Cheng-Hong "[Isomorphism determination methods for simple undirected graphs](https://dds.sciengine.com/cfs/files/pdfs/0254-4156/E4E524DF79EA41CB90588C3A6099FBDA.pdf)", Acta Automatica Sinica, 2023, 49(9): 1878-1888

After read it carefully, a much simpler method is invented based on
$$
Fg :=Ag + M + r \cdot I
$$
where

- $Ag$ is the adjacency matrix,
- $M$ is a $n\times n$ matrix whose entries are equal to $m$
- $I$ is the identity matrix,
- $m$, $r$ are free variables.

Under the above conditions, then
$$
\det(Fg) = \det(Fh) \iff g\text{ and }h\text{ are isomorphic.}
$$
Note that

- this is true for all undirected graphs (except for one unknown case: $g$ has different number loop for nodes).
- It's similar to Jones polynomial generalized to HOMFLY for knot theory (by introducing a second variable $m$).

Though it is strong, but for digraphs, it is not always true even with more constrains.

Comment: Is $M$ a matrix with every element equal to $m$?  If so your claim fails for every pair of graphs that are cospectral with cospectral complements. There are many such pairs, for example any pair of cospectral regular graphs.

Comment: The DOI cannot be resolved: I added a direct link to the cited paper, though it may get "old".

Comment: @BrendanMcKay  Thank you,  you are right.  There is a gap between my "prove".